# Having an issue pulling an Inbound Email's attachments and saving it to a Task

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I'm working with a new custom inbound email service, and in my testing I'm managing to pull all the necessary information to the task I'm creating for it, but for some reason the attachments aren't coming with.  If anyone has any insight it would be appreciated.  I already check to ensure that the settings for the service is set to accept all attachments, so it shouldn't be blocking anything.  This is the handler that I have so far:

```
global class AA_InboundEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope){

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String sbj = email.subject;
    sbj = sbj.substringAfterLast('-').trim();
    try{
        result = createTask(sbj, email);
        }
    catch(exception e){
        system.debug('Unexpected Object Type');
        result.success = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

public static Messaging.InboundEmailResult createTask(string sbj, Messaging.InboundEmail email){
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    string name;
    sObject r;
    ID ownerID;
    try{
        if(sbj.startsWith('001')){
            Account a = new Account();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Account WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Contact   
        else if(sbj.startsWith('003')){
            Contact a = new Contact();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Contact WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Lead  
        else if(sbj.startsWith('00Q')){
            Lead a = new Lead();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Lead WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Opportunity   
        else if(sbj.startsWith('006')){
            Opportunity a = new Opportunity();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }

        // Turn email body into note
        Task task = new Task(ActivityDate = Date.today(),
                            CallDisposition = 'Email Received from Client',
                            CallType = 'Inbound',
                            Description = email.plainTextBody,
                            Status = 'Completed',
                            Subject = 'Email from: ' + email.fromAddress,
                            Type = 'Email',
                            WhatId = r.Id);

                            if(sbj.startsWith('001')){
                                task.Account__c = r.Id;
                                }
                            //Contact   
                            else if(sbj.startsWith('003')){
                                task.Contact__c = r.Id;
                                }
                            //Lead  
                            else if(sbj.startsWith('00Q')){
                                task.Lead__c = r.Id;
                                }
                            //Opportunity   
                            else if(sbj.startsWith('006')){
                                task.Opportunity__c = r.Id;
                                }
            insert task;

        Task newTask = new Task(Description =  email.htmlBody,
                                Priority = 'Normal',
                                Status = 'New Email received for ' + name,
                                Subject = email.subject,
                                IsReminderSet = TRUE,
                                WhatId = r.Id,
                                Type = 'Email',
                                ReminderDateTime = System.now()+1,
                                OwnerId = ownerID);
        // Insert the new Task
        insert newTask; 
        // Save attachments, if any
        for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
            attachment.ParentId = task.Id;
            insert attachment;
            }

            //Save any Binary Attachment

            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
            attachment.ParentId = task.Id;
            insert attachment;
            }
            result.success = true;
            }
    catch(Exception E){
        result.success = false;
        }   
    return result;
    }
```

}

Comment: First of all: You should not use a DML-Statement inside a for-loop. You may hit the governor limits here. Add records to a list and insert it after the loop. What exactly do you mean by " attachments aren't coming with"? Are there no attachments handled in the class? Or are no attachments created to your org?

Comment: No attachments are created in the org.  I'm aware of the governor limit concern, I am more focused on getting it working at this stage than making sure the process was efficient, given it can easily be addressed once it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that anyone seemed too interested, but the fault was the result of the in-context user being different than that of the Task owner I was attaching the processed files to.  System didn't like that, but it wasn't clear until some further digging.  Anyway, here's the final result without issue in case it helps someone in the future:

```
global class AA_InboundEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope){

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String sbj = email.subject;
    sbj = sbj.substringAfterLast('-').trim();
    try{
        result = createTask(sbj, email);
        }
    catch(exception e){
        system.debug('Unexpected Object Type');
        result.success = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

public static Messaging.InboundEmailResult createTask(string sbj, Messaging.InboundEmail email){
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    string name;
    sObject r;
    ID ownerID;
    Task newTask;
    try{
        if(sbj.startsWith('001')){
            Account a = new Account();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Account WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Contact   
        else if(sbj.startsWith('003')){
            Contact a = new Contact();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Contact WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Lead  
        else if(sbj.startsWith('00Q')){
            Lead a = new Lead();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Lead WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }
        //Opportunity   
        else if(sbj.startsWith('006')){
            Opportunity a = new Opportunity();
            a = [SELECT ID, OwnerID, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE ID =: sbj];
            r = a;
            name = a.Name;
            ownerID = a.OwnerID;
            }

        newTask = new Task(Description =  email.htmlBody,
                                Priority = 'Normal',
                                Status = 'New Email received for ' + name,
                                Subject = email.subject,
                                IsReminderSet = TRUE,
                                WhatId = r.Id,
                                Type = 'Email',
                                ReminderDateTime = System.now()+1,
                                OwnerId = ownerID);
                                if(sbj.startsWith('001')){
                                    newTask.Account__c = r.Id;
                                    }
                                //Contact   
                                else if(sbj.startsWith('003')){
                                    newTask.Contact__c = r.Id;
                                    }
                                //Lead  
                                else if(sbj.startsWith('00Q')){
                                    newTask.Lead__c = r.Id;
                                    }
                                //Opportunity   
                                else if(sbj.startsWith('006')){
                                    newTask.Opportunity__c = r.Id;
                                    }

            // Insert the new Task
            insert newTask;
            // Save attachments, if any
        list<Attachment> attachList = new list<Attachment>();
        if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
            for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                // attach to the newly created contact record
                attachment.ParentId = newTask.Id;
                attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
                attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
                attachment.OwnerID = ownerID;
                attachList.add(attachment);
                }
            }

          if (email.textAttachments != null && email.textAttachments.size() > 0) {
            for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.textAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                // attach to the newly created contact record
                attachment.ParentId = newTask.Id;
                attachment.Name = email.textAttachments[i].filename;
                attachment.Body = blob.valueOf(email.textAttachments[i].body);
                attachment.OwnerID = ownerID;
                attachList.add(attachment);
                }
            }

            if(!attachList.isEmpty()){
                insert attachList;
                }
            result.success = true;

        }
    catch(Exception E){
        result.success = false;
        }
    return result;
    }
```

}